# Can file recovery tools recover deleted small files from SSD drive's NTFS Master File Table?

Tags: windows, file-system, data-recovery, ssd, trim

According to this [page](https://books.google.com/books?id=bfpmDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA15) and [site](https://superuser.com/questions/1185461/maximum-size-of-file-that-can-be-stored-entirely-in-ntfs-master-file-table-mft/1185466#1185466), small files are kept in Master File Table when filesystem is NTFS.

Let's assume that computer is using Windows 10 and a SSD drive with TRIM support. If a user manually deletes a file smaller than 1kb from ssd will TRIM erase that file from MFT or is it recoverable at there?

How about the backup MFT located at the end of the partition? Will TRIM remove that small file from backup MFT?

**Can file recovery tools recover erased small files from SSD drive's NTFS Master File Table?**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this particular scenario, but I would expect that TRIM does **NOT** wipe small file MFT content.

TRIM wipes a deallocated (deleted) **file**.

The MFT is a **file**. Removal of a small *file entry* from the MFT deallocates the MFT entry header, marking it as available. The MFT **file** is not deleted, so TRIM would not run against an entry in the MFT.

Similarly deleted database *entries* on an SSD are not wiped by TRIM because the database **file** is never deleted.

So yes, under the right circumstances and tools, recovery is possible.